# Can we explain to undergraduates how points make a line?

Tags: undergraduate-education, geometry, infinity

Many of my students arrive in college believing that lines are (in some way) made out of points.

They also believe that points have no length.

They want to know how a bunch of zero length points make a line of length 1?

Edit
I did ask this question in math.stackexchange, but because it is about teaching it was declared off topic and closed.  I changed to question there in hopes that if I understood it better, then I might be able to explain it.

I have asked my original question here in mathematics education in hopes of hearing teaching advice. I see it as a question about geometry and teaching geometry although it comes up in a class on ideas of infinity.

Comment: It seems you have little experience with this topic.  So my advice is: follow the textbook exactly.  At the elementary level, you should not tell students that a line is made out of points.  After all, from before Euclid until about 1900, we did geometry without thinking that a line is made out of points.

Comment: Whether lines are made up of indivisible points was a big discussion topic among Medieval philosophers.

Comment: Carl Boyer: *The History of the Calculus and Its Conceptual Development*, Chapter III is one reference.

Comment: Just want to chime in that this wasn't just a question among medievals, but for instance was a big bone of contention at the time of development of calculus.  Cavalieri, Torricelli, and Hobbes are all good (if divergent) primary sources on this.

Comment: By the way, to be helpful to the actual question, since you have identified the course as such, I think you should "teach the question".  The answer is "yes", there is a paradox and a lot of people have thought about this a lot without coming to a good conclusion.  As much as I dislike its stridency and tail-wagging-the-dog, Amir Alexander's book Infinitesimal takes on a lot of these concepts well; Doug Jesseph's book on the Hobbes/Wallis controversy is better but definitely at a higher level.

Comment: The question could use a tag such as undergraduate education or secondary education, but I don't know which is relevant. @JimH, could edit in the relevant tag?

Comment: One way to avoid your problem would be to say that for every line, we have a uniquely determined set of points that lie on this line. As we can reconstruct the line uniquely from the set of points, this set can be considered as "making up" the line. In this way, we associate the set of points to the line, we don't claim that they are equal. This is similar to the question whether we consider two isomorphic vector spaces as "equal", which leads many students in first year linear algebra to think that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the only vector space in existence...

Comment: You have made the same question in other community! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417029/how-can-points-that-have-length-zero-result-in-a-line-segment-with-finite-length

Comment: @Cragfelt The question about explaining it was closed due to being oiff topic.  Apparently we should not ask questions about explaining things to students there.  I have edited my question here to address this.

Comment: In smooth infinitesimal analysis (SIA), it is false that a line is made of points. *Can we do better than "There are uncountably many points and uncountably many zeros can add up to any number you like."?* I don't see anything in this discussion that requires it to be an uncountable infinity. The issue you're talking about would also occur for the rational number line.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold  Thank you.  I think that's a good approach for my students (college freshmen).  When this question comes up in class, my students have read and discussed Aristotle's Physics Book III, chapter 4.  So they are probably ready for this approach, which, in spite of the actual infinity, has a bit of an Aristotelian feel to me.

Comment: Your students are more or less right: when you put a finite number of points next to each other, the total length will be zero. When you put an infinite, but countable, number of points next to each other, the length will still be zero. It's only when the "number" of points becomes not only infinite, but also uncountable (which is why I put the word "number between brackets) that you might get a length, different than zero. But you can only explain this to your students if they are capable of understanding the different levels of infinity.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I came up with thinking about your question.

I would start by exploring what it means to say that a line is 'made up of' points, because I think that is a really important thing that doesn't get taught in schools. Students know 'the equation of a line', but usually have no real concept of what that means.

Admittedly, that will be somewhat tricky if they have not done an introduction to sets. I would perhaps try using plotting points:

> Imagine using a computer to plot '$y=3x+2$' on the screen by looking at each pixel at a time. Pick one pixel. It has an $x$ coordinate and a $y$ coordinate. We check whether these points satisfy the equation. That is, if we put the two numbers into the equation '$y=3x+2$', do we end up with a statement that is true, or a statement that is false? If it's true, that means the pixel is on the line, and we colour it red. It it's false, that means it is not on the line, so we colour it blue. Once we've done this for all the pixels, we'll have our picture of the line.'

I'd then look at the [Paradoxes of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes). The ideas go a bit beyond what most of the students will need, but the starting point is within reach, and it's reasonably easy for students to find out more if they are interested. If nothing else, it might make some of them think.

I'd end by saying that really understanding the answer to the original question means studying measure theory. There are two reasons I see for pointing this out. Firstly, it assures the students that it's ok that they do not understand, because what they are asking is more advanced than the maths they have done. But it also points out that is isn't magic, or made up. There is a real answer out there, that they could reach if they really put their minds to it.

Comment: Thank you.  I phrased the question as I did in hopes that others might find any answers interesting and useful.  I teach freshman mathematics at a liberal arts college.   This question arises in a writing seminar I teach centered on "Ideas of Infinity".  Many of the students are liberal arts majors. I have the students read some of Aristotle's Physics. We do discuss Zeno's Paradoxes and Galileo's paradox and supertasks.  I use some intuitions about sets.  Late in the course I present the idea of cardinality including "countable" and "uncoutable".

Comment: Re, pixels:  A computer screen only has a finite number of discrete pixels, and it is easy to define a line that crosses the screen but does not contain any of its pixels.  Actual line-drawing algorithms color pixels based on how far each one lies from the line.

Comment: @jameslarge The point isn't to actually discuss drawing a line on a computer, it's to make a picture the students can understand to help them grasp a new idea.

Comment: @jameslarge: Last time I took such a course, *actual* line-drawing algorithms were doing integral delta-steps from one endpoint to the other (no distances involved). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, The Bresenham algorithm _selects_ the connected set of pixels that lies closest to the actual line.  I emphasise "select" because it doesn't do anti-aliasing:  That is, it does not attempt to truly render a sampled image of a finite-width line.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: @jameslarge: One could just as easily say "actual" line drawing algorithms plot the pixels containing the line, as opposed to algorithms that look to construct a pleasing optical illusion rather than trying to render the line. The reality of the matter is different algorithms to achieve different results for different purposes.

Comment: @Hurkyl, My original comment was very unclear, but it was meant to be about the nature of pixels, and not about line-drawing algorithms. I'd love to argue with you about whether "plot the pixels containing the line" is or is not just a special case of "color [the] pixels according to how far they lie from the line," but that would be way off the topic of the question.

Answer (score 4):

They don't. You need *additional information* to organize a set of points into anything resembling geometry; a bare set of points is simply lacking the context to allow anything more interesting than counting them (i.e. the cardinality of the set).

A typical form of context boils down to "remembering" how the points are embedded in a Euclidean plane.

Below are two answers I've given to similar questions at https://math.stackexchange.com. Both questions have a variety of other answers to browse through as wel.

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1084093/14972
- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1805439/14972

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the premise, lines are (in some way) made out of points, and points have no length.

If, restricting ourselves to a straight line, we can consider these as subsets of the real numbers $\Bbb R$.

A line is a subset of this with the property, if $a, b \in \Bbb L$ then any real number between $a, b$ is in $\Bbb L$.

Calling elements of a line points, we can define the length of the line between the two points (on a straight line) say $a, b$  as the distance between them, and this distance is $\left|b - a\right|$. The length here being a property of two points, on a line, rather than the sum of a property of all individual points.

We could mention subsets of the real numbers, even with uncountably many elements, where ways to measure a length gives zero, such as the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), and these do not contain line segments.

> They want to know how a bunch of zero length points make a line of length 1?

I find this tough. We could consider a line $[0,1]$ of length $1$ as divided into $n$ segments of length $\frac{1}{n}$.

The total length of these segments is $\frac{n}{n} = 1$ while as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the length of the segments $\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 2):

Often the fact that words have connotations in common parlance which are at odds with the more technical way these words are used within mathematics causes tensions in getting ideas across to students. But the notion of point and line are especially subtle.

Euclid gives definitions for the words point and line but by the time Hilbert and others came along, point and line were left as undefined in axiom systems that were developed to understand the Euclidean plane and other kinds of geometry. So one can construct "models" that satisfy a collection of axioms that involve point and line as undefined terms and give an interpretation to these words in the model. If one picks any of Hilbert's axioms, say A, one can construct a model where the interpretations of point and line satisfy each of the axioms other than A and where A fails to hold.

To help show what can go on I like to show students finite geometries. Some students get the "point" here but most just don't accept the fact that the "lines" of these finite geometries are "really" lines! You might find this brief introduction to finite geometries of interest:

http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-finitegeometries

And then there is the model where points are pairs (x,y) where x and y are rational numbers and lines are linear equations with rational coefficients - a geometry which is not the Euclidean plane but has lines with lots of points between any pair of points, but lots of "holes," too.

Answer (score 1):

This question alludes to a deep developmental issue. Your students are starting to think hard about the continuum, even if they do not realize it. A countable collection of points (for example rational numbers) in [0,1] has Lebesgue measure zero. Yet the collection of all points in [0,1] has Lebesgue measure 1. But of course the notion of Lebesgue measure was not fully developed until the early 20th century. Perhaps an undergraduate would get to this understanding in an upper division analysis course, but most do not.

Another perspective is from projective plane geometry. Here points and lines are both undefined terms, and they are on the same footing. By projective duality, ranges of points (points incident with a given line) are logically the same as pencil of lines (lines incident with a given point). In other words, instead of thinking as points as fundamental and deriving lines as ranges of points which is what we tend to do, we could take lines as the fundamental objects and ``derive'' points by considering pencils of lines.

I point out these two notions not because they will be of immediate help to younger undergraduate mathematics students, but to indicate to the OP just how deep the question is.

Answer (score 1):

> They want to know how a bunch of zero length points make a line of
>   length 1?

It may help to think of the Euclidean plane as a set, each element of it being a point in the plane. Then any geometric figure (e.g. a line, or a circle) would be a subset of the Euclidean plane, each element of that subset being a point in the plane.

**Example 1:** A subset of the plane P is a circle iff there exists a point C in P and a distance r such that every point in that subset is a distance r (the radius) from the point C (the center).

$$\{ X \in P : |CX| = r\}$$

**Example 2:** A subset of the plane P is a straight line iff there exists a pair of distinct points A and B in P such that every point in that subset is equidistant from both A and B.

$$\{ X\in P : |AX| = |BX|\}$$

Comment: I do not like Example 2 (understood as a definition), as it uses the euclidean structure while "line" is an affine concept.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I don't understand your objection, but both examples use only the concept of the distance between a pair of points in the plane.

Comment: that is my point, circle *need* the notion of distance to be defined (well, even this is debatable), but clearly the notion of line does *not* need the notion of distance. For example, very many transformations of the plane send lines to lines, but do not (in general) preserve distances: affine transformations. It would thus be wrong to *define* lines using distance while "line" is an affine notion, not a metric one.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I tried to think of the simplest selection criterion for points in the plane that would form a line without using axioms for betweeness, etc. L = {X in P: |AX| = |BX|}. My point being that a line is just a subset of the Euclidean plane, each element of which is a point.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner The students in question don't seem to have a problem with the notion of finite distances, so I built on that.

Comment: I am not saying that the notion of distance is too complicated. I am saying that defining a line in the way you do is emphasizing a secondary property of the concept. I think that the choice of definition we make should reflect the idea we have when we introduce the concept, not be just any property that happens to characterize the concept.

Comment: Arguably, the notion of line is almost too primitive to be defined without some technology (vectors), and one could either take it as a primitive concept (explaining the idea but not giving a formal definition) or take alignment of three point as the primitive concept and define lines from that. Nowhere do I dispute the "subset of the plane" approach, but the fact the the set of points equidistant from two points is a line should be a property (an interesting one at that), not a definition.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner You may have to show my definition is equivalent to which ever one you prefer.

Comment: I do know your definition is logically equivalent to any other usual one. That does not make it a *good* definition, as it insists on something that is not prime to the concept. But we are circling, I guess I said what I have to say.